# I am unable to check a input checkbox element

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically generated this checkbox element and I am trying to check it dynamically.
Here is how I am doing it:

```
var id = "123"; //dynamically generated

var input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("name", "x_"+id);
input.setAttribute("id", "x_"+id);
input.setAttribute("value", "");

input.setAttribute("checked",true);  //This isn't working

var elem = document.getElementById('x_' + id);
elem.checked = true;      //This isn't working
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have only 1 element w/ that ID? And is the element being selected via `elem`? Throw a `console.log(elem.id)`. Also you're not adding the newly created element to the body or any other element, so it's not there yet

Comment: It's simpler to work with properties rather than attributes, so `input.type = 'checkbox';`, etc. ;-)

Comment: Sorry for missing that information!. I am appending the input element to a table row. I just figured that document.getElementById('x_123'); works!! But accessing the document.getElementById('x_'+id) is not checking the element.

Answer (score 3):

You never actually add the element to the page. It works here, just need to do:

```
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

---

```js
var id = "123"
var input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("name", "x_"+id);
input.setAttribute("id", "x_"+id);
input.setAttribute("value", "");

input.setAttribute("checked",true);  //This isn't working

document.body.appendChild(input);

var elem = document.getElementById('x_' + id);
elem.checked = true;      //This isn't working`enter code here`
```